# ApexChart x-axis does not show decimal numbers in the labels

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I have a problem with ApexChart in React. It does not show decimal numbers in the labels of the x-axis and repeats integers instead. It seams like it rounds in the integer. However when go with mouse on the bar it shows the correct value (maybe because of the tooltip I added). Furthermore I wanted to know how I can "artificially" extend the axis to a certain value.

```
this.state = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                height: '600',
                type: 'rangeBar',
                toolbar: {
                    show: true,
                    autoSelected: 'selection'
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: true,

                }
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'right'
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'numeric',
                title: {
                    text: 'ms'
                },
                labels: {
                    show: true
                },
                decimalInFloat: 3,
            },
            tooltip: {
                custom: ({ dataPointIndex, w }) => {
                    let s = w.config.series[0].data[dataPointIndex];
                    return `<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-rangebar"><div>
                <span class="category">${s.x}: </span>
                <span class="value start-value">${s.y[0]}</span>
                <span class="separator">-</span>
                <span class="value end-value">${s.y[1]}</span></div></div>`;
                }
            },
        },
        series: [
            {
                data: []
            }
        ],
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `formater` for `xaxis` to round to decimal place you want

```
xaxis: {
  ...
  labels: {
    formatter: function (val) {
      return val.toFixed(1);
    }
  }
},
```

> Furthermore I wanted to know how I can "artificially" extend the axis to a certain value.

Set `max` value in `xaxis`